# Create a view with uuid_generate_v4()

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, uuid

I have a problem and have no idea how to solve it.
I need to create a view (let's name it "revision") from another view which updates very frequently.
In my view "revision", I have all the columns from another view table + a unique id for that I use uuid_generate_v4().

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS 
(
SELECT uuid_generate_v4() AS gid, fw.* 
FROM First_view fw
);
```

The view itself looks ok, however, my problem is that I need to have stable gid as I am going to use my view to populate another table and I need to use gid as a reference so I need stable ids, but as view always runs the query, every time it generates a new gid.
I was thinking about creating a new rule but was not able to figure out how it can help.

What should I do to avoid this problem? Is there at all any solution to overcome this problem?

Thanks
Mani

Comment: The obvious solution would be not the bother with the view at all, just select data directly into the other table.  Perhaps a materialized view might work but I don't see the point.

Comment: If there is no unique identifier in the data from `first_view`, you won't be able to releatably generate one. Yes, you should tell us the bigger picture; why you think you need that.

Comment: Have you tried using a `materialized view`? Bjarni and Laurenz have good points though ;)

Comment: I try to give the bigger picture.
I have a catalog with a very complicated schema (all tables are related together through revision ids and by PK and FK relations). I need to register some of the data from another database into the catalog db however the whole purpose is "data virtualization". In practice, this means I am not allowed to store any data from remote db directly into my catalog db instead I shall provide them in view. For this, I am planning to create part of the catalog schema/tables in view. For that, I need stable UUID in almost all my views.

Comment: So, my approach is that I use fdw to connect to the remote db, create a view (first view) in which I query all those information/data I need from remote db.
Now I want to start creating those tables I have from my catalog in view and select corresponding values from "first_view". But for each table then I need to have unique and stable ids.

Comment: @JimJones I am not quite familiar with the materialized view but I guess it stores physically the data. no?

Comment: @ManiMosh I will add it in an answer for you to try. But I suspect I misunderstood your use case :-D

Comment: you should put that "bigger picture" into your question, not into comments. (btw: the parentheses around the SELECT are unnecessary)

Comment: Your "bigger picture" raises the question as to why you need a different key. I assume that is the purpose of the uuid, If you cannot store it then you do not need a different key as it serves no purpose. Just identify as your key use the existing PK from the foreign table. If you cannot do so and must have your own stable key then you MUST create and updated a permanent table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is static, you might wanna use a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`. It will ensure that the values remain unchanged until you run a `REFRESH`, e.g.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_view AS 
SELECT uuid_generate_v4() AS gid, 'foo';



SELECT * FROM test_view;
                 gid                  | ?column? 
--------------------------------------+----------
 5a789003-dd0e-4aa0-a324-890cb7adf007 | foo
(1 Zeile)


SELECT * FROM test_view;
                 gid                  | ?column? 
--------------------------------------+----------
 5a789003-dd0e-4aa0-a324-890cb7adf007 | foo
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: Thanks Jim for this. Following up on my story  (extended in the comments under my post)  The problem is specifically the update / in this case Refresh. So there might be the case that in the remote db only 1 attribute e.g. maintainer = 'x' changes which it has to be updated at the end in the view but I just want to update that updated value(s) while gid remains as it is. It looks to me that neither view nor materialized view could help.

Comment: @ManiMosh you're right, in that case views aren't really an option for you. I might add that your use case is quite unusual :) I'm afraid you'll have to either put ids in the records from the fdw source or create your own, map them to the records and put them to a table, but again you're not allowed to store them... quite hard. Let me know if I should rather delete this answer, so that we all contribute to keeping SO clean ;)

Comment: and anyway it looks that materialized_view stores data which in this case it does not make sense and if I have to go for storing option then I will just go with my tables
anyway thanks.

Comment: @ManiMosh yes, tables would do just fine. The only advantage of a materialized view would be the `REFRESH` feature instead of dropping or truncating a table and repopulating it ;) cheers